# Check if thread is main thread

Tags: c#, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I'm running some tests on our large app, and I see sometimes the UI thread doing stuff it was not supposed to, like DB/network/etc.

I know of `IMvxMainThreadDispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction`, but I would like something like:

`public bool IsMainThread()`

Which would return true if current thread is the main thread.

Before I go and create a PR for this code, I just wanted to double check if something similar is not yet available in another way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've found something that can help me here.

```
        DebugEx.Assert(Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId != 1);
```

On a PCL library, where we do not have Threading.CurrentThread, finding out about the value on `Environment` just helped me find a pesky deadlock we were searching for a long time.
Usually 1 is the UI Thread, but to be sure, put a BP on any UI thread code and double check the value.

Also, my Assert is below:

```
    // The [DebuggerHiddenAttribute] makes debugger stop
    // on the actual DebugEx.Assert(...) call, rather than inside 
    // the DebugEx.Assert(...) method itself.
    [DebuggerHiddenAttribute]
    public static void Assert(bool condition)
    {
        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            if (!condition)
            {
                Debugger.Break();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Assert(condition);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps someone else out there.

Comment: It's entirely possible to have a different thread be the UI thread of your application.

Comment: Yes, and exactly for that reason I said:

*to be sure, put a BP on any UI thread code and double check the value.*